# Determining the most common word from a user's input. [Python]

Tags: python, string, list, count

The way I tried to solve this problem was by entering the words of a user into a list and then using .count() to see how many times the word is in the list. The problem is whenever there is a tie, I need to print all of the words that appear the most amount of times. It works only if the words that I use aren't inside of another word that appears the same amount of times. Ex: if I use Jimmy and Jim in that order, it will only print Jimmy.

```
for value in usrinput:
        dict.append(value)
    for val in range(len(dict)):
        count = dict.count(dict[val])
        print(dict[val],count)

        if (count > max):
            max = count
            common= dict[val]
        elif(count == max):
            if(dict[val] in common):
                pass
            else:
                common+= "| " + dict[val]
```

Comment: Should `['Jimmy', 'Jim']` count 1 for Jimmy and 2 for Jim?

Comment: It should count 1 for each.

Comment: off-topic : Don't use `max` as a variable name, it masks the built-in function `max()`

Comment: More significantly: Don't use `dict` as a variable name, especially not for something that isn't a Python dict!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class. I'll give you a hint.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = Counter()
>>> a['word'] += 1
>>> a['word'] += 1
>>> a['test'] += 1
>>> a.most_common()
[('word', 2), ('test', 1)]
```

You can extract the word and the frequencies from here.

Using it to extract frequencies from user input.

```
>>> userInput = raw_input("Enter Something: ")
Enter Something: abc def ghi abc abc abc ghi
>>> testDict = Counter(userInput.split(" "))
>>> testDict.most_common()
[('abc', 4), ('ghi', 2), ('def', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `collections.defaultdict`?

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for value in usrinput:
    d[value] += 1
```

To get the most common words sorted descending order by the number of occurences:

```
print sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]
```

Comment: Not if you're using a version < python2.7.

Comment: Looking at the OP's code, it is clear he's using py3.x . BTW defaultdict won't work for <py2.5.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Looking at the OP's code, he's using `dict` as a variable name for something that isn't even a dict, so we can't be sure he isn't just printing a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Rather that concatenating to common where `"Jim" in "Fred|Jimmy|etc"` is true use a list to store the found max values and then print  `"|".join(commonlist)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick and dirty solution, not elegant at all, and uses numpy.

```
import numpy as np

def print_common( usrinput ):
    '''prints the most common entry of usrinput, printing all entries if there is a tie '''
    usrinput = np.array( usrinput )
    # np.unique returns the unique elements of usrinput
    unique_inputs = np.unique( usrinput )
    # an array to store the counts of each input
    counts = np.array( [] )
    # loop over the unique inputs and store the count for each item
    for u in unique_inputs:
        ind = np.where( usrinput == u )
        counts = np.append( counts, len( usrinput[ ind ] ) )
    # find the maximum counts and indices in the original input array
    max_counts = np.max( counts )
    max_ind    = np.where( counts == max_counts )
    # if there's a tie for most common, print all of the ties
    if len( max_ind[0] ) > 1:
        for i in max_ind[0]:
            print unique_inputs[i], counts[i]
    #otherwise just print the maximum
    else:
        print unique_inputs[max_ind][0], counts[max_ind][0]

    return 1

# two test arrays which show desired results
usrinput = ['Jim','Jim','Jim', 'Jimmy','Jimmy','Matt','Matt','Matt']
print_common( usrinput )

usrinput = ['Jim','Jim','Jim', 'Jimmy','Jimmy','Matt','Matt']
print_common( usrinput )
```